# Verifying a signature with a public certificate

Tags: openssl, digital-signature

I'm studying the idea of signing and then verifying the signature of a message using OpenSSL. I have the signature part figured out, but I'm stuck verifying that same signature.

Say that I have some plaintext in a file called plaintext.txt. I have the signature of the plaintext in signature.txt. This plaintext was signed using a private RSA key. I have the certificate which contains the public key that goes with that private key. I believe that there is an OpenSSL command that will allow me to verify that signature without extracting the public key as a separate step. Here is what I am trying:

> openssl sha1 -verify -inkey cert.pem -certin -signature signature.txt plaintext

But I'm getting this error on the command line:

> No signature to verify: use the -signature option

Comment: Could you please add the command you have used for signature generation? There are multiple signature formats supported by OpenSSL and this would help to clarify your question.

Comment: It looks like `-signature` is being passed as an argument to `-certin` like any other file. Perhpas that's a typo that should be corrected first. Something like `... -certin cert.pem -signature signature.txt ...`. Also, rather than `openssl sha1 -verify`, you should probably be using Jariq's suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume that you have your PEM encoded X.509 signing certificate stored in file "signer.cer" and your PEM encoded PKCS#1 private key stored in file "signer.key".

You can use OpenSSL command line utility to sign the file "plaintext.txt" and output the signature stored in PEM encoded PKCS#7 structure into the file "signature.p7s":

```
openssl smime -sign -binary -in plaintext.txt -signer signer.cer -inkey signer.key -outform PEM -out signature.p7s
```

You can use following command to verify the signature:

```
openssl smime -verify -binary -inform PEM -in signature.p7s -content plaintext.txt -certfile signer.cer -nointern -noverify > /dev/null
```

If you are using Windows then just replace `/dev/null` with `nul`.

See [OpenSSL SMIME module manual](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/smime.html) for more details about individual options.